# Can you export a video from Premiere Pro to an SWF file?

Tags: premiere

Can you export a video from Premiere Pro to an SWF file?

Comment: Do you mean FLV?  SWF would be a very odd output choice for full motion video.  SWF normally provides the player (and is generally being moved away from with HTML5 now supporting direct video playback).  FLV or F4V are the actual video streams that the SWF players playback.